# ssrs iif expression reporting

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

I do not want to display ZDATEB(date) value when ZJNSBYR is blank(no value).
Example of data as below:

```
ZJNSBYR ZDATEB
-----------------------
    20190728
    20190728
```

and ZDATEB(date) will be displayed as 28-08-2019 if there is value for ZJNSBYR

I have tried this :

```
iif(Fields!ZJNSBYR.Value=' ', Fields!ZDATEB.Value=' ',right(Fields!ZDATEB.Value, 2) & "-" & mid(Fields!ZDATEB.Value, 5, 2) & "-" & left(Fields!ZDATEB.Value, 4))
```

I follow this example:

```
IIF(Fields!ExitReason.Value = 7, 1, 0)
```

But got this error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Value expression for
>   the textrun ‘ZDATEB5.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error:
>   [BC30201] Expression expected.    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005Impl.SetReportDefinition(String
>   Report, Byte[] Definition, Warning[]& Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010Impl.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]&
>   Warnings)    at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.SetItemDefinition(String
>   ItemPath, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, Warning[]&
>   Warnings)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is your expected Result.
How did I achieved it.
Below is the expression.

Note: Your field name can vary depending on what you have in your Database.

```
=IIF(Isnothing(Fields!ZJNSBYR.Value) or Fields!ZJNSBYR.Value="" ,nothing,Format(Fields!ZDATEB.Value,"dd-MM-yyyy"))
```